# Django custom Widget failing on choices above 1 (enter whole number)

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-forms

I wanted a multiState clickbox. So I spend some free time on a nice Django solution that makes it:

```
class MultiStateChoiceInput(forms.widgets.ChoiceInput):
    input_type = 'radio'
    def __init__(self, name, value, attrs, choice, index, label_id):
        # Override to use the label_id which is upped with 1
        if 'id' in attrs:
            self.label_id = attrs['id']+ "_%d" % label_id

        super(MultiStateChoiceInput, self).__init__(name, value, attrs, choice, index)

        self.value = force_text(self.value)


    @property
    def id_for_label(self):
        return self.label_id

    def render(self, name=None, value=None, attrs=None, choices=()):
        if self.id_for_label:           
            label_for = format_html(' for="{}"', self.id_for_label)
        else:
            label_for = ''
        attrs = dict(self.attrs, **attrs) if attrs else self.attrs
        return format_html(
            '{} <label{}>{}</label>',  self.tag(attrs), label_for, self.choice_label
        )


class MultiStateRenderer(forms.widgets.ChoiceFieldRenderer):
    choice_input_class = MultiStateChoiceInput

    outer_html = '<span class="cyclestate">{content}</span>'
    inner_html = '{choice_value}{sub_widgets}'

    def render(self):
        """
        Outputs a <ul> for this set of choice fields.
        If an id was given to the field, it is applied to the <ul> (each
        item in the list will get an id of `$id_$i`).

        # upgraded with the label_id
        """
        id_ = self.attrs.get('id')
        output = []
        for i, choice in enumerate(self.choices):
            choice_value, choice_label = choice
            if isinstance(choice_label, (tuple, list)):
                attrs_plus = self.attrs.copy()
                if id_:
                    attrs_plus['id'] += '_{}'.format(i)
                sub_ul_renderer = self.__class__(
                    name=self.name,
                    value=self.value,
                    attrs=attrs_plus,
                    choices=choice_label,
                    label_id = (i+1) % (len(self.choices))  # label_id is next one
                )
                sub_ul_renderer.choice_input_class = self.choice_input_class
                output.append(format_html(self.inner_html, choice_value=choice_value,
                                          sub_widgets=sub_ul_renderer.render()))
            else:
                w = self.choice_input_class(self.name, self.value,
                                            self.attrs.copy(), choice, i,  label_id = (i+1) % (len(self.choices)))  # label_id is next one
                output.append(format_html(self.inner_html,
                                          choice_value=force_text(w), sub_widgets=''))
        return format_html(self.outer_html,
                           id_attr=format_html(' id="{}"', id_) if id_ else '',
                           content=mark_safe('\n'.join(output)))


class MultiStateSelectWidget(forms.widgets.RendererMixin, forms.widgets.Select):
    ''' This widget enables multistate clickable toggles 
    Requires some css as well  (see .cyclestate)
    '''
    renderer = MultiStateRenderer
```

This creates a form like is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455783/3849359 and where a click toggles the next state until it reached the and and then continues at the beginning.

The form is called in my view like:

```
SomeFormSet= modelformset_factory(myModel, form=myModelForm, extra=0)    
SomeFormSet.form = staticmethod(curry(myModelForm, somevariable=somevariable))

formset = SomeFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=somequeryset)
```

And forms.py is:

```
class myModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES = (
       (0, _('a')),
       (1, _('b')),
       (2, _('c')),
       (3, _('d')),
       )


    field = forms.IntegerField(widget=MultiStateSelectWidget(choices=CHOICES))


    class Meta:
        model = MyModal
        fields = ('field',)
        widgets = {'id': forms.HiddenInput(),
                 }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.variable= kwargs.pop('variable')
        super(myModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for field in myModelForm.fields:

            if self.instance.pk:

                if not getattr(self.instance, field):
                    self.initial[field]= 0
                else:
                    self.initial[field]= 1

                if anothercondition:
                    self.initial[field] = 3
                else:
                    self.initial[field] = 2
```

I thought it worked very well. And the clicking and saving does work wel (I have a custom save method). Except when the form field has a value of 2 or 3, then it suddenly failes with the error message: 'field' should be a whole number.

If anyone could help that would be great, as I'm out of ideas!

EDIT: Just in case... I have checked the POST and it is great. The only problem is that Django somewhere in parsing the POST loses the value completely (it becomes None) if the value is a 2  and I have no idea why.

EDIT2: It seems that the Django ModelForm does also do model validation. And the model is a BooleanField, which is the reason why it fails. If anyone knows a good way to override it, that would be nice!

Comment: Change the model field to IntegerField to save an integer. You cannot save an integer in a boolean field. I think that this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@edgarzamora Your comment is not the answer, but it is close!

I removed the 'field' from the Form class Meta, so it looked like:

```
class Meta:
    model = MyModal
    fields = ('',)
    widgets = {'id': forms.HiddenInput(),
             }
```

And now everything works, because I have my custom save method... So stupid, it costed me hours! Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Seems good! Also you can mantain the 'field' in the fields tuple, and override the field in the init function instead of declare a new one field. But my question is, if you said that your model field is a boolean field, how can you save integeres between 0 and 3 ? This part is confusing me..

Comment: In my save method I convert the integer (0 to 3) to a boolean (0, 1), plus it executes some additional functions when it is 2 or 3. The same way when initializing the function, it converts an integer to 0 or 1 and executes some functions to check if it should be a 2 or 3 instead.

Comment: Okey! You forgot to explain that. The next time should be better to share the model code too. Thanks!

Comment: The save method is in the forms.py too :) But when researching the problem, I found that form.is_valid is never true, which means that the save method was never called and the problem should be before that, and SO was already complaining I had too much code :) But thanks again for the headsup! :)